# Function to concat undefinded number of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, function, arguments, concatenation

I'd like to create a function where I can input an undefined number of arrays, turn them into data frames ,concatenate them appending their columns and output a merged dataframe.

Example:

```
# Suppose we have 3 arrays:

data1 = {
    'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
    'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5'],
    'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'],
    }
data2 = {
    'D': ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5'],
    'E': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5'],
    'F': ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5'],
    }
data3 = {
    'G': ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'],    
    'H': ['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5'],
    'I': ['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5'],
    }

# We could convert them into data frames using:
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

# And finally join them with:
df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
```

The output dataframe would look like this:

[image: Output_Dataframe]

I would like to create a function that can do this, but with an unspecified amount of arrays, for example:

```
func(data1, data2)

func(data1, data2, data3)

func(data1, data2, data...n)
```

Comment: `def func(*args): d = [pd.DataFrame(dc) for dc in args]; return pd.concat(d, axis=1)`

Comment: This works. ¿Do you want to add it as an answer ?
 Could you also post the function it in its long form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a short answer using list comprehension, provided by Ch3steR.
It works and is a very compact answer.

```
def func(*args): d = [pd.DataFrame(dc) for dc in args]; return pd.concat(d, axis=1)
```

In the end I went for a longer and slower solution, but that i will easily understand when looking at my code in the future:

```
def add_df(*args):
""" Function to concatenate columns of unlimited dataframes"""
list = []
for file in args:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    list.append(df)
return pd.concat(list, axis=1)
```